# shorter way to place data on database

Tags: php, mysql

After collecting variables for an article on client side here is the php code for placing them on a mysql database.

It works but is there a shorter way, without repeating all items - `five times`:
- once in `btn_save` declaration
- twice in `sql` declaration
- twice in `st` execution

```
function btn_save($img, $up, $branch, $title, $sub, $intro, $story, $down, $linked, $tags, $status){
    global $db;
    $sql = "insert into arts (img, up, branch, title, sub, intro, story, down, linked, tags, status) values (:aimg, :aup, :abranch, :atitle, :asub, :aintro, :astory, :adown, :alinked, :atags, :astatus)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([
        ":aimg" => $img,
        ":aup" => $up,
        ":abranch" => $branch,
        ":atitle" => $title,
        ":asub" => $sub,
        ":aintro" => $intro,
        ":astory" => $story,
        ":adown" => $down,
        ":alinked" => $linked,
        ":atags" => $tags,
        ":astatus" => $status
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can pass the associative array as a single argument to the function, instead of creating it in the function. But this just moves some of the duplication to the caller.

Comment: You can use an ORM like Laravel.

Comment: @Barmar, any exemple of this code in Laravel, pls?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use Laravel or any other ORM myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `?` instead of named placeholders and `func_get_args` function, you can reduce you code to:

```
function btn_save($img, $up, $branch, $title, $sub, $intro, $story, $down, $linked, $tags, $status){
    global $db;
    // values as array
    $args = func_get_args();

    // create a string `?, ?, ? ...` with count of `?` same as count of arguments
    $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($args), '?'));

    $sql = "insert into arts (img, up, branch, title, sub, intro, story, down, linked, tags, status) values ($placeholders)";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    // as `$args` already array - just pass it as is
    $st->execute($args);
}
```

The only condition connected with `?` is that order of fields in `insert` should be the same as order of incoming arguments.

Comment: It's also better to pass data as an array which eliminates repetition, makes the code to be more readable, and makes us not to take care of ordering of arguments.

Comment: @agtabesh, example, pls

Comment: I don't see any repetition here.

Comment: @u_mulder what about getting an array of arguments from client side, so in php would be like this - `function btn_save($array)`

Comment: You can do it too, then you don't need `func_get_args`, but approach stays the same.

Comment: But I will prefer list of arguments and here's why - suppose you open this code after some time. You will try to remember how many values and in what order you should put to `array`. Using `list of arguments` any modern IDE will give you a hint what values and in what order should be provided for a function call.

Comment: I see, thanks. Your stuff on SO is extremely helpful, I noticed